# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, formatting

I just asked [this question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97005/is-it-more-generally-accepted-in-academia-that-thales-was-hylozoist-or-panpsychi) and it got downvoted, however no commentary was provided on how to improve it, so, unless it's spam, could anyone please provide me with feedback on what is wrong with it?

EDIT: Also I just got two comments from people with high reputation which clearly show that the question body has not been read carefully. How to act in such a case? I responded and flagged the comments as not relevant, but I am not sure if that is the way to proceed.

Comment: I think it’s an interesting question and not obviously off-topic — please don’t worry about a few downvotes that don’t bother to indicate what they could use more clarity on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is now improved thanks to the comments of a really helpful critic. Since it is a sophisticated question, it needed to be completely clear to avoid misunderstanding.